# Is there an OpenFileOrFolderDialog object in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, filedialog

Is it possible to use the [`OpenFileDialog`](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=10&ct=1221809452&rver=5.5.4177.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http:%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx&id=254354&lc=1033) class select a file OR folder?  It appears only to allow the selection of a file, if you select a folder and then choose open it will navigate to that folder.

If the `OpenFileDialog` can not be used for this is there another object I should be using?

**EDIT**: The scenario is that I have a tool that can upload one...many files or folders.  I need to be able to provide a dialog like the `OpenFileDialog` that allows a user to select a file, folder, or a combination of.  I know about the `FolderBrowseDialog` and that is not the answer in this case.

Comment: Take a look at the **[Ookii Dialogs](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs)** libraries which have an implementation of a folder browser dialog for Windows Forms and WPF respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution I have been looking for, this article provides code and describes how to create a dialog that meets my needs.

[CodeProject: Full Implementation of IShellBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FileDialogs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use OpenFileDialog to select a folder. Here is an article in CodeProject that demonstrated a way to do it (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileOrFolderDialog.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in .NET, I would have to say no, sorry for the negative and short answer, but I really don't think there is

Comment: I think you are right.  Hoping someone here can prove us both wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have time, you can create your own pretty easily by using the [System.Windows.Forms.TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) Class. Each node can have a checkbox, so If you populate the treeview (onexpand) you can let the user select the files/directories he wants to upload.

This should get you started on populating the treeview with directories, the job to also add files in the treeview should not be that hard:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0280__GUI-Applications/FileTreeview.htm

Answer (score 0):

No: the OpenFileDialog is just for opening files. Anyway there is a FolderBrowserDialog you can use for that.

[Edit] Answered too fast: the Edit from the questioner was afterwards.

Comment: From the question: "I know about the FolderBrowseDialog and tha is not the answer in this case."

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at the **[Ookii Dialogs](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs)** libraries which have an implementation of a folder browser dialog for Windows Forms and WPF respectively:

[image: Ookii Folder Browser dialog on Windows 10]

> **Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf**
>
> https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf

---

> **Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms**
>
> https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-winforms