# Required Dialog for selecting Multiple Files and Folders .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

I thought it would be easy to find, I was wrong.

Dialog Requirements:

- Can browse MULTIPLE FILES/FOLDERS in the same time.
- Can be used in .NET windows forms.
- FREE or can be used under GPL.
- Works in Win Xp and Win 7.

Dialog Preferences:

- C#
- Looks like OpenFileDialog in .NET.
- Has textbox for pasting path.

I have tried few examples from WEB, none met all Requirements!

Some examples, closest to solution for now:

- http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.net/class-opendialogmbs.shtml, it is no free
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FileDialogs.aspx, WIN7 problem

Comment: Thanks Scoregraphic, I was just doing same thing when I saw someone else has edited :)

Comment: This previous Stack overflow questions has a similar requirement, and is about changing the folder dialog class to suit your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428410/select-either-a-file-or-folder-from-the-same-dialog-in-net

Comment: I have studied this and several other threads and did not find code that satisfies all requirements. As I remember FolderBrowseDialog does not have multiselect property (REQ1) and is not as functional as OpenFileDialog (PREF2).

Comment: Fair enough, I know finding code for this can be a bit of a pain as even the FolderDialog is missing from the compact framework. I do think the file/folder and message box needs a rewrite in .Net to be more developer friendly.

Comment: Which message box or f*dialog class or method?  I see at least one in several different, seemingly unrelated namespaces.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question? It will be the file dialog class you will be after if you want it edit it to support files and folders.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/SelectDialog.aspx It meets all the requirements, but it's written in Visual C++.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/)?

It should match all your requirements, or be at least a very good starting point.

Comment: This is needed for big project which is not in .NET 3.5, I didn't write this in requirements though. Sorry.

Comment: Also I did not find any dialog that satisfies all requirements in provided solution.

Comment: Maybe I misread your requirements, since it seems that it fits quite nicely. The library provides multi-select functionalities, it can be used in .NET windows form, can be used under GPL, work both in Win XP and Win 7, is written in C#, looks like the OpenFileDialog in .NET and has textbox for pasting text. Of course, if you do not use .NET 3.5, the pre-compiled library is of no use, for you. Still, you could try to migrate the code to .NET 2.0. As I said, can be a very good starting point.

Comment: What about "Can browse MULTIPLE FILES/FOLDERS in the same time"? I haven't found that feature. I can select multiple files only.