# How do I list all files in the selected folder with FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, folderbrowserdialog

I want to list all the files in a treeview with C++/CLI. The folder needs to be selected with FolderBrowserDialog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select either a file or folder from the same dialog in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428410/select-either-a-file-or-folder-from-the-same-dialog-in-net)

Comment: I got it working by myself so no problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115%28VS.85%29.aspx)?