# Is there an alternative to EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel which can accept folders as well?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel` can only target files.

`EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel` can only target folders.

I need one that can target either a file or folder at the user's discretion.

Comment: There is no built-in method, but you can achieve that by [doing P/Invoke the related Win32 API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25738110/3427520).

Comment: That looks pretty complicated and would only work in Windows wouldn't it? I guess I'll just try to work around the problem.